# Pegar os dados relacionados a mais de uma tabela, separadamente?

Tags: php, mysql, query, pdo, crud

Não estou conseguindo de maneira nenhuma fazer isso.
Parece ser com o join, mas quando tento, me retorna zero registros.

Tenho as tabelas:
TB1, TB2, TB3, TB4, TB...etc
Todas com PK (ID)

Tentei esse codigo:

```
SELECT ID
FROM TB1
inner join TB2 on (TB1.ID = TB2.ID)
inner join TB3 on (TB1.ID = TB3.ID)
inner join TB4 on (TB1.ID = TB4.ID)
```

Aqui ele só vai exibir o ID que for comum nas quatro TB's. Eu quero que mostre se aparecer em qualquer uma delas.

Comment: Romulo, não entendi a relação entre as tabelas. Você relacionar ID com ID, sendo eles PK, teoricamente está errado se não tem relação sempre 1 = 1, em todas as tabelas. Você teria que ter um campo numa tabela principal, com FK para as outras tabelas. Ou então detalhe melhor seu cenário, pois não faz sentido. Caso tenha dúvidas em como melhorar sua pergunta, dê uma olhada: [Como criar um exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Eu quero comprar uma tabela principal com outras varias tabelas. Toda vez que um registro da tabela principal for encontrado em qualquer uma das outras tabelas, não em todas, ele aparecerá no select.

Comment: Entendi, mas você tem que ter relação entre elas. Exemplo: `TB1.campoX` será FK de `TB2.ID`. E assim cada um com sua FK com a "tabela principal"

Comment: Não consigo comparar a PK da principal com campos índices nas outras?
Tenho que ter FK's?

Comment: Não tem lógica isso. Você sempre ter o mesmo ID pra várias outras tabelas como relacionamento. Pense em um cadastro de "pessoas" e as outras tabelas que são "estado", "município", "telefones" (que poderá ter mais de 1), etc como teria ligação? Isso ainda é só 1 hipótese, existem várias outras.

Comment: Essas dados inseridos nas outras tabelas eram criados no código PHP em que estou trabalhando. Sempre que um registro era criado na principal, o código adiciona nas outras tabelas, num campo de mesmo nome, o mesmo valor. Esse mesmo valor, não é PK nem FK. Estão definidos como 'KEY' nas outras tabelas. Estou trabalhando num código que já esta pronto a anos. No caso, eu teria então que trocar esse campo 'KEY' para FK e fazer o relacionamento normalmente com inner join?

Comment: Só para ficar mais claro é isso:
Eu tenho uma tabela de pedidos, é a principal. 
Esses pedidos podem vir de 10 lugares diferentes.
Toda vez que algo de errado acontece com esse pedido, é criado em um outra tabela, um registro com o numero desse pedido (o num do pedido é PK na tabela principal) para indicar que tem algo errado. Ela guarda pedidos com problemas, por isso não da para ser FK. Nâo são todos que vão para lá, e são imprevisíveis.
Há 10 tabelas diferentes, cada uma representando um lugar de origem do pedido, que são preenchidas.

Comment: Então... Não tem uma coluna que fale de onde vem? Seria legal você postar exemplo real, facilita entendermos para te ajudar...

Answer (score 0):

Table pedidos (tb_pedidos):

```
id_pedido (PK) | person_id | descrição   | preço
------------------------------------
1              | 1         | iphone 5    | 100
2              | 1         | iphone 6    | 200
3              | 1         | samsung Tv  | 300
4              | 2         | samsung APT | 110
5              | 3         | Phillips TV | 250
6              | 3         | Phillips ph | 260
```

Table Apple_Extravio:

```
id (PK) | id_pedido | description | data
------------------------------------
1       | 1         | Perda       | 24/07/2017
2       | 2         | Roubo       | 08/07/2015
```

Table Samsung_Extravio:

```
id (PK) | id_pedido | description | data
------------------------------------
3       | 5         | Indefinido  | 16/06/2014
```

Table Phillips_Extravio:

```
id (PK) | id_pedido | description | data
------------------------------------
N       | N         | N           | N
```

É basicamente isso. A tabela principal de pedidos. E as outras são preenchidas quando o pedido tem algum problema de entrega.
Todas vez que algo acontece o código php insere as informações nas outras tabelas, de sua respectiva marca.
Isso só ocorre quando um problema é relatado pelo entregador, e o funcionário responsável entra no sistema com esse dado.
A tabela já esta criada a anos e tem mais de 200 mil registros.

Então o que eu estou fazendo:
Numa outra tela, preciso exibir os registro que tiveram problemas.
Preciso comparar o 'id_pedido' da tabela principal com os das tabelas de extravio. Sempre que o id_pedido for encontrado em qualquer uma das tabelas de extravio, vai para lista e é exibido.

Da forma como estou tentando fazer, não esta funcionando:

```
SELECT id_pedido
FROM tb_pedidos as p
INNER JOIN Apple_Extravio ae ON (p.id_pedido = ae.id_pedido)
INNER JOIN Samsung_Extravio se ON (p.id_pedido = se.id_pedido)
INNER JOIN Phillips_Extravio ON (p.id_pedido = pe.id_pedido)
```

Isso me mostra 0 resultados.